# Error: The digital signature of the Object did not verify

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to install VS 2013 on windows and it give below error.

> Error: The digital signature of the Object did not verify

**[I already checked this post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466802/why-do-i-keep-getting-the-digital-signature-of-the-object-did-not-verify-for-w)** but in my installer file there is no tab with the name of Digital Signature in File Properties.

Please guide me to right direction.

Below is the screenshot of error.

[image]

Comment: You need to add more information:: what exactly displays this error? what process? what window? etc.

Comment: Did you "examine the log file"...? The fact that there's no Digital Signature tab suggests that the file, whichever one it is (which one is it?) doesn't have a digital signature...

Comment: Of course you always need to see a Digital Certificates tab on the installer's file properties.  The Ultimate edition license retails for a fat four thousand dollars, too much inspiration for bootleg copies in some parts of the world.  Like yours.  You need to document where you got it from.

Comment: Sounds like an error indicating that the installation file is not valid. Where did you get the installer? Try and download it again from a legitimate source.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can occur for many reasons, you can try out the following options for the resolution of problem.

**Option 1** - The problem could be with the iso file, which you are using to install Visual studio. Get [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20190602145847/https://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290) tool to verify your iso file by following the steps described [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/verify-the-iso-checksum-for-visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1-before-installing/).
In that case get an different image for **install visual studio using web installer**.

**Option 2** - There might be some problem that prevent you from installing some updates or programs. Perform steps as listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/cannot-install-updates-programs) or even better, download the "*Fix it Package*" executable provided in the same link, and run it.

**Option 3** - You can also try running the setup from the location, from where web installer runs it which is by default - *C:\Users(Your username)\Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013*

**Option 4** - Update your windows, and try reinstalling Visual Studio.

Also please refer to the following forum post - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/24bdde43-89df-496e-bbb4-089141bd57c6/setup-failed-visual-studio-code-features-enu-the-digital-signature-of-the-object-did-not-verify?forum=vssetup

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify your VS 2013 version.

Did you use ISO file to install visual studio 2013?

If it is, have you verify the ISO file. Base on the error message, I suggest you first verify the ISO file.

you use this tool http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290 to verify hash of the ISO. The point of the exercise is to generate a hash value (SHA1) from the ISO file so that it can be checked against the known value for that file. Any discrepancy would indicate that the file was corrupted.

The SHA1 value could be found at the download webpage.

If the installation still fails after verifying the ISO file and it is good, please use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the latest installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.cab from %temp% folder.

Best Regards.